# SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()

Tags: android

I have an Editor instance, but it is consistently failing to commit() for a handful of my users:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(..., ...);
if (!editor.commit()) {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure why this would be failing for them (all my thousands of other users run those lines ok). Is there any way to get more information here? I'm just logging the fact that the commit() return value is false, so at least I know what's going on, but not sure how to fix,

Thanks

Comment: If possible, try to get LogCat information around the point of the error (e.g., if you are using ACRA and are logging this problem using it, temporarily add the `READ_LOGS` permission to automatically grab 200 lines from LogCat). There are a few scenarios in which `commit()` can return `false`, by my read of the source code, but they should all log errors which would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Are preferences being commited elsewhere (another thread)? This can happen if there is a conflict.

Comment: Prefs not being committed elsewhere. These happen to be done on the main thread in an AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method. I'm going to try getting the logcat output today as suggested.

Comment: I haven't been able to capture any log output yet, but confirmed that the user is on a Samsung Infuse running "FROYO.UCKH1". They have no option to upgrade to even gingerbread at this point! I sent them a new version which simply has a button which writes to shared prefs on a click, and that simple test fails. Still working to capture the logs, not sure if any will be printed for this though - is it possible this is a bug specific to this carrier's build of Froyo?

Comment: So confirmed that other users with this same problem are all running "FROYO.UCKH1", grrr.

Comment: did you found a solution ? I have a similar problem on a samsung device...